# cakephpのsearchプラグイン(複数キーワードによる検索)

Tags: cakephp

cakephp2.7で簡単なサイトを作っていて、サイト内の検索機能を付けたいのでsearchプラグインをインストールしました。 
いくつかサイトを調べて以下のように記述したら、とりあえず検索できるようにはなりました。 
↓Hoge.php(モデル)

```php
Class Hoge extends AppModel{
public $actsAs = array(        
        'Search.Searchable'
    );
public $filterArgs = array(
        array(
        'name' => 'search_value', 
        'type' => 'like', 
        'field' => array('Hoge.q_body','Hoge.expl'),
    )
);}
```

↓HogesController.php

```php
class HogesController extends AppController{
public $scaffold;

public $components = array(
        'Search.Prg'
    );

public $presetVars = array(
         array(
              'field' => 'search_value', 'type' => 'value'
    ),
);

public $paginate=array(
    'limit'=>50
);

function show(){//検索用アクション
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $conditions = $this->Hoge->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs);

    $this->set('hoges', $this->paginate(array(
                $conditions,
            ))
    );
}
```

さらに調べてモデルを上記のように書くことで複数カラムの検索もできるようになったのですが、半角スペースで区切って複数のキーワードによる検索をできるようにしたいです。 
調べた結果、$filterArgsを

```php
class Hoge extends AppModel{
public $actsAs = array(
        'Search.Searchable'
    );
public $filterArgs = array(
        array(
        'name' => 'search_value', 
        'type' => 'like', 
        'field' => array('Hoge.q_body','Hoge.expl'),
                'connectorAnd' => ' ', 
                'connectorOr' => ','
    )
);
}
```

のようにすればよい、とあり、試した結果

```
Fatal Error

Error:  Class 'String' not found 
File:  C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp2\app\Plugin\Search\Model\Behavior\SearchableBehavior.php 
Line:  358
```

上記のエラーが出ます。どこが悪いでしょうか？どうすれば複数のキーワードによる検索ができるようになるでしょうか？

Comment: search プラグインのソースコード上でエラー箇所を見ると、`String::tokenize` を実行しようとしたけど `String` クラスがないよ、という事になっている様です。`String` クラス(実体は `CakeText` クラス)を view 以外で使う場合は明示的にロードする必要があって、この場合は `show()` 関数の最初に `App::uses('String', 'Utility');` を入れる必要があるらしいです。ただ、こちらには実行環境がないので確認が取れません。